# summation of series (odd and even case)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone please answer this for me,it involves alternate signs which is different from normal summation formula.

Q:Find the sum to n terms of the series $ 1^3 - 2^3 + 3^3 - 4^3 + \ldots -(n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 - n^3 $.

Comment: Can you calculate the sum of $k^3$? If so, could you not subtract the a series that uses the even values? Notice $(2n)^3 = 8n^3$.

Comment: Thx for hint.I will try to solve

Answer (score 1):

The situation is a little different in the case $n$ even than in the case $n$ odd. We deal with even $n$, say $n=2k$, and leave the case $n$ odd to you.

Our sum is equal to 
$$\left(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +(2k)^3\right) -2\left(2^3+4^3+6^3+\cdots+(2k)^3\right).$$
This is equal to
$$\left(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +(2k)^3\right) -16\left(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+k^3\right).$$

Now use the perhaps familiar fact that
$$1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +w^3=\left(\frac{w(w+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thx for answering.I will try to figure it out

Comment: You are welcome. It is a matter of substituting, and (if required) simplifying. For the case $n=2k+1$, you just need to add $(2k+1)^3$ to the answer for $2k$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j}j^3 = -\sum_{j=1}^{n}j^3 +2\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(2j)^3=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{n^2(2n+3)}{4}&\text{if}&n\equiv 0\pmod{2}\\\frac{(n+1)^2(2n-1)}{4}&\text{if}&n\equiv 1\pmod{2}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Thx for answering